# ifstream not working with variable parameter using C++11 and c_str() appended

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, ifstream, getline

Note: I am using the C++11 standard, so I don't see why this isn't working with or without `c_str()` appended.

I have the following code:

```
// open streams
ifstream in(input);
ofstream out(output);

// get which file to open
in.ignore(INT_MAX, ':');  // we don't need the beginning part
in.ignore();              // remove trailing whitespace
string fileLocation;
getline(in, fileLocation);

 out << "Loading: " << fileLocation << endl;
cout << "Loading: " << fileLocation << endl;

// now that we know where the file is, load it:
ifstream file(fileLocation);
```

which reads from a file that looks vaguely like this

```
File: file.txt
(Subcommands below)
```

I know that I am pulling the correct filename because of the terminal output.

Anyway, I noticed that the stream wasn't opening properly, so I added this conditional to check:

```
if ( !file )
{
    cout << "File wasn't loaded properly." << endl;
}
```

And sure enough, I see that message when running the program.

My question is this: how come, when I hard-code the file location, e.g. `ifstream file("file.txt")` it opens up no problem? How do I get this working properly?

Comment: Maybe there are non-printable characters in the filelocation, such as whitespace.  `in.ignore()` means to discard exactly one character (whether or not it is whitespace)

Comment: If you are still having trouble, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with an exact input file that causes the problem

Comment: Set a breakpoint and use your debugger to check what exactly is in `fileLocation` when you pass it to `ifstream` constructor. Perhaps there is some whitespace after all

Comment: Could be a path issue. The directory where the program is run could be different from where you expect to see the file. Using an absolute path would fix that.